# Undefined value after using .parentElement

Tags: jquery

I don't know why but when I use `.parentElement` I get undefined but in Chrome debbuger I see that there is form, where is the bug?

```
$('.ZamIlosc').each(function () {
                var tdstan = $(this).parentElement; 
   // ...forward code
```

Comment: I don't think you can use parentElement on a jQuery object.  Try `.parent()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `this.parentElement` (an attribute of the element) or `$(this).parent()` (jQuery's function to get the parent element).

By surrounding `this` with `$( )` you're turning it into a jQuery object, which requires the usage of `.parent()` instead of `.parentElement`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read a property that doesn't exist in jQuery.

`$(this)` is a jQuery object that wraps a DOM node, and you can't directly access the DOM node property like you are attempting.

You have two options:

```
$(this).parent() //returns another jQuery object wrapping the parent node

this.parentElement //references parent DOM node
```